# Using vite-plugin-api-routes breaks build

Tags: vite

I work with a small UI framework and need an API for testing the upload component. We use Vite to power our documentation site and thought the [vite-plugin-api-routes](https://github.com/yracnet/vite-plugin-api-routes) would be a great fit.

Indeed everything worked out fine for the dev server (plain `vite` command), but when building for production (`vite build`) we get the following error message:

```
vite v5.1.4 building for production...
✓ 556 modules transformed.
computing gzip size (2)...vite v5.1.4 building SSR bundle for production...
✓ 0 modules transformed.
x Build failed in 2ms
x Build failed in 2.20s
error during build:
Error: [vite-plugin-rest-api] [vite:define] Transform failed with 3 errors:
error: Invalid define value (must be an entity name or valid JSON syntax): ..
error: Invalid define value (must be an entity name or valid JSON syntax): /
error: Invalid define value (must be an entity name or valid JSON syntax): /api
file: /Users/.../ui-library/packages/ui-docs/.api/server.js
file: /Users/.../ui-library/packages/ui-docs/.api/server.js
    at failureErrorWithLog (/Users/.../ui-library/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1651:15)
```

We have tried a number of different ways to get passed this and it seems to be related to this [issue with Vite and the import.meta.env](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/3304). It is used in all setups I've tried in the `vite-plugin-api-routes` and always ends up breaking the build. As a side note we are using a mono repo setup with npm workspaces.

Any ideas or suggestions on what we could try to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving away from vite-plugin-api-routes. After some more research I figured that it was probably easier for our tiny test API to be hosted by Node instead.

Writing a node server taking care of the API was easy enough with Express (from my `server.js` file):

```js
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.get('/api/hello', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ hello: 'world' });
});
```

With a bit of configuration for the dev environment I ended up with a solution where the Vite dev server was started in parallel with the Node (`server.js`). This was quite straight forward with [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) package.

For the production environment, a section was added to the `server.js` file to get the static files served along side the API routes:

```js
// Serve static files (only in production)
if (production) {
  const dirname = new URL('.', import.meta.url).pathname;
  app.use(express.static(path.join(dirname, 'dist')));
}
```